# Update Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 on Dell PowerEdge R630

Tags: updates, dell

I have a PowerEdge R630 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and want to update it to ubuntu 18.04. In 16.04. PowerEdge R630 is in support list of ubuntu but in Version 18.04. DELL PE R630 is not listed, should i nevertheless updating to 18.04 or is there a high risk?

Comment: Why should be any risk?

Comment: because unsupported Hardware and drivers f.e. Raid controller etc. Never touch a running system after my controllers doesnt work and i have to stop my webseite

Comment: How it became unsupported? Support of hardware is not removed in new kernels unless the hardware is VERY old.

Comment: This is just because the Server is not listed anymore in list: https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201409-15513; a bit confused because of this the Server is from 2016. But i think this helps, i will try :-)

Comment: This means that it is not certified. Canonical doesn't certify every peace of hardware on every Ubuntu release.

Comment: ok :-) thank you this helps, i was just insecure because of this